# Problem understanding FTester syntax

Tags: firewall, testing

I want to test my firewall with the tool `ftest` in Kali Linux aka FTester.

My both hosts are Debian systems with `iptables` as firewall/packet filter. When sending packets from one host to the other, I would like to check whether the firewall is working properly or not.

The syntax is not quite clear to me:

```
sourceaddress:sourceport:destinationaddress:destinationport:protocol:flag:tos
```

What port and what flag should be used to get it work? Should a flag be considered with the port?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to test the firewall is to use nmap. Here's and example that tests 3 IPs:

```
sudo nmap -A --reason -Pn -sT -vv 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i want to test my firewall with the tool ftest in Kali Linux aka FTester.

Comment: Yep, that's what you said. No problem.